# Open Gl ES 2.0 Triangles always black

Tags: java, android, opengl-es

I recently started coding with OpenGL ES 2.0 and ran into a (for me) quite challenging problem. This is my first try, streaming VBO Buffer Objects dynamically ( at least that's what I think I am doing). My application should draw 2 triangles in a specific color, but instead they are just black. I think it's possible that I mixed up some GL commands, but I can't find the problem.

Here's a snippet from my GLRenderer class:

```
@Override
public void onSurfaceCreated(GL10 unused, EGLConfig config) {



    /* Draw black background */
    GLES20.glClearColor(0.8f, 0.6f, 0.4f, 1.0f);

    {...}

    viewMatrix = camera.getMatrix();

    /* Create and compile shaders */
    int vertexShaderHandle = loadShader(vertexShader, GLES20.GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
    int fragmentShaderHandle = loadShader(fragmentShader, GLES20.GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);

    /* Create and link program */
    programHandle = loadProgram(vertexShaderHandle, fragmentShaderHandle);

    /* Set references for drawing input */
    mVPMatrixHandle = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(programHandle, "uMVPMatrix");
    positionHandle = GLES20.glGetAttribLocation(programHandle, "vPosition");
    colorHandle = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(programHandle, "vColor");
    checkGlError("glGetUniformLocation");

    /* Create 2 Triangles for testing purposes. */
    final float[] triangle1Vertex = { 0.0f,  0.5f, 0.0f,
           -0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f,
            0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f,};
    final float[] triangle2Vertex = { -1.0f,  1.0f, 0.0f,
            -1.0f, -0.5f, 0.0f,
            -0.5f, 1.0f, 0.0f};

    /* Color */
    final float[] color = { 0.63671875f, 0.76953125f, 0.22265625f, 0.0f};

    /* Init triangles */
    Triangle triangle1 = new Triangle(triangle1Vertex, color);
    Triangle triangle2 = new Triangle(triangle2Vertex, color);

    /* Add triangles to be drawn */
    TriangleCollection.add(triangle1);
    TriangleCollection.add(triangle2);

    /* Create buffer objects in GPU, 2 buffers are needed */
    final int buffers[] = new int[2];

    GLES20.glGenBuffers(2, buffers, 0); //Generate GPUSide Buffers

    /* Allocate GPU memory space for vertices */
    GLES20.glBindBuffer(GLES20.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, buffers[0]);
    GLES20.glBufferData(
            GLES20.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,
            TriangleCollection.MAX_NUMBER_OF_VERTICES * TriangleCollection.BYTES_PER_FLOAT,
            TriangleCollection.publishVerticesBuffer(),
            GLES20.GL_STREAM_DRAW);
    checkGlError("glBufferData");


    /* Allocate GPU memory space for color data */
    GLES20.glBindBuffer(GLES20.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, buffers[1]);
    GLES20.glBufferData(
            GLES20.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,
            TriangleCollection.NUMBER_OF_COLOR_ELEMENTS * TriangleCollection.BYTES_PER_FLOAT,
            TriangleCollection.publishColorBuffer(),
            GLES20.GL_STREAM_DRAW);
    checkGlError("glBufferData");

    GLES20.glBindBuffer(GLES20.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);

    /* Reference the GPU Buffers */
    triangleVerticesIdx = buffers[0];
    triangleColorsIdx = buffers[1];

    GLES20.glFlush();

    startTime = System.nanoTime();
}

@Override
public void onDrawFrame(GL10 unused) {

    FloatBuffer vertices = TriangleCollection.publishVerticesBuffer();
    FloatBuffer colors = TriangleCollection.publishColorBuffer();

    /* Upload triangle data */
    GLES20.glBindBuffer(GLES20.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, triangleVerticesIdx);
    GLES20.glBufferSubData(GLES20.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0, vertices.capacity() * Triangle.BYTES_PER_FLOAT, vertices);
    checkGlError("glBufferSubData");

    /* Upload color data */
    GLES20.glBindBuffer(GLES20.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, triangleColorsIdx);
    GLES20.glBufferSubData(GLES20.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0, colors.capacity() * Triangle.BYTES_PER_FLOAT, colors);
    checkGlError("glBufferSubData");

    GLES20.glBindBuffer(GLES20.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);

    /* Clear Screen */
    GLES20.glClear(GLES20.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT | GLES20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    GLES20.glUseProgram(programHandle);

    /*Matrix calculations */
    Matrix.setIdentityM(modelMatrix, 0);
    Matrix.multiplyMM(mvpMatrix, 0, projectionMatrix, 0, viewMatrix, 0);
    GLES20.glUniformMatrix4fv(mVPMatrixHandle, 1, false, mvpMatrix, 0);
    checkGlError("glUniformMatrix4fv");

    /* Pass the position information */

    GLES20.glBindBuffer(GLES20.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, triangleVerticesIdx);
    checkGlError("glBindBuffer");
    GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(positionHandle);
    checkGlError("glEnableVertexAttribArray");
    GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(positionHandle, Triangle.COORDINATES_PER_VERTEX, GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
    checkGlError("glVertexAttribPointer");


    /* Pass the color information */

    GLES20.glBindBuffer(GLES20.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, triangleColorsIdx);
    checkGlError("glBindBuffer");
    GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(colorHandle);
    checkGlError("glEnableVertexAttribArray");
    GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(colorHandle, TriangleCollection.COLOR_SIZE_FLOAT, GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
    checkGlError("glVertexAttribPointer");


    /* Clear currently bound buffer  */
    GLES20.glBindBuffer(GLES20.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
    checkGlError("glBindBuffer");

    //Draw
    GLES20.glDrawArrays(GLES20.GL_TRIANGLES, 0, TriangleCollection.MAX_NUMBER_OF_VERTICES);
    checkGlError("glDrawArrays");

}
```

This code runs without errors and I already checked the FloatBuffers in Debug Mode. They contain the required information.

I would also appeciate any feedback on the general concept of my drawing / rendering pipeline. I'm not sure weather this is a good solution but at least I get 30 FPS @8000 Triangles on my Nexus 5.

#### Edit 1

After some testing I got the following results:

1. According to the log I'm using EGL 1.4. I do not intend to use OpenGL ES 3.0 for now ( Provided that this is possible).

2.Replacing vColor element of the fragment shader with a constant value works. The triangles are red:

```
final String fragmentShader =
"precision mediump float;" +
"uniform vec4 vColor;" +
"void main() {" +
"  gl_FragColor = vec4(1.0,0.0,0.0,1.0);" +
"}";
```

3. When using the normal non-static fragment shader, removing this part of the code changes absolutely nothing:

   /* Pass the color information */

   ```
   GLES20.glBindBuffer(GLES20.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, triangleColorsIdx);
   checkGlError("glBindBuffer");
   GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(colorHandle);
   checkGlError("glEnableVertexAttribArray");
   GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(colorHandle, TriangleCollection.COLOR_SIZE_FLOAT, GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
   checkGlError("glVertexAttribPointer");
   ```
4. Removing colorHandle = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(programHandle, "vColor"); from surfaceCreated() works as usual, no triangle is drawn.

#### Edit 2

I still can't find my mistake. While using glGetUniformLocation worked for one triangle, it doesn't work for many. I stripped down my project to a simple test application so I can show the complete code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private MySurfaceView mySurfaceView;

@Override
protected  void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    /* Create SurfaceView and add it to Activity */
    MySurfaceView = new MySurfaceView(this);
    setContentView(mySurfaceView);

}


@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    MySurfaceView.onPause();
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    MySurfaceView.onResume();
}
}

public class MySurfaceView extends GLSurfaceView {

private final GLRenderer renderer;

/**
 * Creates the SurfaceView
 * @param context Application context
 */
public MySurfaceView(Context context) {
    super(context);

    setEGLConfigChooser(8, 8, 8, 8, 16, 0);

    /* OpenGl Version GLES 2.0 min */
    setEGLContextClientVersion(2);

    /* Add Renderer for drawing */
    renderer = new GLRenderer();
    setRenderer(renderer);

}
}




public class GLRenderer implements GLSurfaceView.Renderer {

/* Frame Counter */
private int nbFrame = 0;
private long startTime;

/* Vertex Shader */
final String vertexShader =
        // This matrix member variable provides a hook to manipulate
        // the coordinates of the objects that use this vertex shader
        "uniform mat4 uMVPMatrix;" +
                "attribute vec4 vPosition;" +
                "void main() {" +
                // the matrix must be included as a modifier of gl_Position
                // Note that the uMVPMatrix factor *must be first* in order
                // for the matrix multiplication product to be correct.
                "  gl_Position = uMVPMatrix * vPosition;" +
                "}";
/* Fragment Shader*/
final String fragmentShader =
        "precision mediump float;" +
        "uniform vec4 vColor;" +
        "void main() {" +
        "  gl_FragColor = vColor;" +
        "}";
/* Reference for the program */
private int programHandle;

/* References to pass data into shader */
private int mVPMatrixHandle, positionHandle, colorHandle;

/* Projection matrix, used for projection 3D scene to 2D viewport. */
private float[] projectionMatrix = new float[16];

/* Model matrix used for moving Models around */
private float[] modelMatrix = new float[16];

/* Combined Matrix */
private float[] mvpMatrix = new float[16];

/* Matrix of the camera position and perspective */
private float[] viewMatrix;

/* Reference to the buffer of the triangle vertices in the GPU DDR */
private int triangleVerticesIdx;

/* Reference to the buffer of the triangle colors in the GPU DDR */
private int triangleColorsIdx;

/**
 * Load shader
 */
static int loadShader(final String shader, int type) {

    int shaderHandle = GLES20.glCreateShader(type);

    if (shaderHandle != 0) {
        GLES20.glShaderSource(shaderHandle, shader);
        checkGlError("glShaderSource");

        GLES20.glCompileShader(shaderHandle);
        checkGlError("glCompileShader");

        final int[] compileStatus = new int[1];
        GLES20.glGetShaderiv(shaderHandle, GLES20.GL_COMPILE_STATUS, compileStatus, 0);

        if (compileStatus[0] == 0) {
            GLES20.glDeleteShader(shaderHandle);
            shaderHandle = 0;
        }
    }

    if (shaderHandle == 0) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Error while creating shader");
    }

    return shaderHandle;
}

/**
 * Loads a OpenGL ES 2.0 program with a vertex and a fragment shader.
 * @param vertexShader
 * @param fragmentShader
 * @return
 */
public static int loadProgram(int vertexShader, int fragmentShader) {
    int programHandle;

    /* Load program */
    programHandle = GLES20.glCreateProgram();

    if (programHandle != 0) {
        /* Bind shaders to program */
        GLES20.glAttachShader(programHandle, vertexShader);
        checkGlError("glAttachShader");
        GLES20.glAttachShader(programHandle, fragmentShader);
        checkGlError("glAttachShader");

        /* Bind Attributes */
        GLES20.glBindAttribLocation(programHandle, 0, "vPosition");
        checkGlError("glBindAttribLocation");
        GLES20.glBindAttribLocation(programHandle, 1, "vColor");
        checkGlError("glBindAttribLocation");

        /* Link shaders */
        GLES20.glLinkProgram(programHandle);

        /* Get link status... */
        final int[] linkStatus = new int[1];
        GLES20.glGetProgramiv(programHandle, GLES20.GL_LINK_STATUS, linkStatus, 0);

        if (linkStatus[0] == 0) {
            GLES20.glDeleteProgram(programHandle);
            programHandle = 0;
        }
    }
    if (programHandle == 0) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Error creating program.");
    }

    return programHandle;
}

@Override
public void onSurfaceCreated(GL10 unused, EGLConfig config) {



    /* Draw black background */
    GLES20.glClearColor(0.8f, 0.6f, 0.4f, 1.0f);

    /* Create Camera and define values -> calculate Matrix */
    Camera camera = new Camera();
    camera.setPosition(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.5f);
    camera.setPerspective(0.0f, 0.0f, -5.0f);
    camera.setUpVector(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
    camera.setMatrix();

    viewMatrix = camera.getMatrix();

    /* Create and compile shaders */
    int vertexShaderHandle = loadShader(vertexShader, GLES20.GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
    int fragmentShaderHandle = loadShader(fragmentShader, GLES20.GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);

    /* Create and link program */
    programHandle = loadProgram(vertexShaderHandle, fragmentShaderHandle);

    /* Set references for drawing input */

    mVPMatrixHandle = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(programHandle, "uMVPMatrix");
    positionHandle = GLES20.glGetAttribLocation(programHandle, "vPosition");
    colorHandle = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(programHandle, "vColor");
    checkGlError("glGetUniformLocation");

    /* Create 2 Triangles for testing purposes. */
    final float[] triangle1Vertex = { 0.0f,  0.5f, 0.0f,
           -0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f,
            0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f,};

    /* Color */
    final float[] color = { 0.0f, 0.76953125f, 0.22265625f, 1.0f,
            0.0f, 0.76953125f, 0.22265625f, 1.0f,
            0.0f, 0.76953125f, 0.22265625f, 1.0f};

    /* Create Vertex Buffer */
    ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(triangle1Vertex.length*4);

    bb.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());

    FloatBuffer vert1 = bb.asFloatBuffer();

    vert1.put(triangle1Vertex);
    vert1.position(0);

    /* Create Color Buffer */
    ByteBuffer bb1 = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(color.length*4);

    bb1.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());

    FloatBuffer color1 = bb1.asFloatBuffer();

    color1.put(color);
    color1.position(0);

    /* Create buffer objects in GPU, 2 buffers are needed */
    final int buffers[] = new int[2];

    GLES20.glGenBuffers(2, buffers, 0); //Generate GPUSide Buffers

    /* Allocate GPU memory space for vertices */
    GLES20.glBindBuffer(GLES20.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, buffers[0]);
    GLES20.glBufferData(
            GLES20.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,
            1*9*4,// 9 floats for triangle and 4 bytes per float
            vert1,
            GLES20.GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    checkGlError("glBufferData");


    /* Upload FPU memory space for color data */
    GLES20.glBindBuffer(GLES20.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, buffers[1]);
    GLES20.glBufferData(
            GLES20.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,
            1*3*4*4,
            color1,
            GLES20.GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    checkGlError("glBufferData");

    GLES20.glBindBuffer(GLES20.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);

    /* Reference the GPU Buffers */
    triangleVerticesIdx = buffers[0];
    triangleColorsIdx = buffers[1];

    GLES20.glFlush();

    startTime = System.nanoTime();
}

/**
 * Not needed. Device must be in landscape mode all the time.
 *
 * @param unused -
 */
@Override
public void onSurfaceChanged(GL10 unused, int width, int height) {

    /* Define Viewport */
    GLES20.glViewport(0, 0, width, height);

    /* Create perspective projection */

    final float ratio = (float) width / height;
    final float left = -ratio;
    final float right = ratio;
    final float bottom = -1.0f;
    final float top = 1.0f;
    final float near = 1.0f;
    final float far = 10.0f;

    Matrix.frustumM(projectionMatrix, 0, left, right, bottom, top, near, far);
}

@Override
public void onDrawFrame(GL10 unused) {

    /* Measure FPS */
    nbFrame++;
    if(System.nanoTime()-startTime >= 1000000000) {
        Log.d("FPS", Integer.toString(nbFrame));
        nbFrame = 0;
        startTime = System.nanoTime();
    }

    /* Clear Screen */
    GLES20.glClear(GLES20.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT | GLES20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    GLES20.glUseProgram(programHandle);

    /*Matrix calculations */
    Matrix.setIdentityM(modelMatrix, 0);
    Matrix.multiplyMM(mvpMatrix, 0, projectionMatrix, 0, viewMatrix, 0);
    GLES20.glUniformMatrix4fv(mVPMatrixHandle, 1, false, mvpMatrix, 0);
    checkGlError("glUniformMatrix4fv");

    /* Pass the position information */

    GLES20.glBindBuffer(GLES20.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, triangleVerticesIdx);
    checkGlError("glBindBuffer");
    GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(positionHandle);
    checkGlError("glEnableVertexAttribArray");
    GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(positionHandle, 3, GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
    checkGlError("glVertexAttribPointer");


    /* Pass the color information */

    GLES20.glBindBuffer(GLES20.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, triangleColorsIdx);
    checkGlError("glBindBuffer");
    GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(colorHandle);
    checkGlError("glEnableVertexAttribArray");
    GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(colorHandle, 4, GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
    checkGlError("glVertexAttribPointer");


    /* Clear currently bound buffer  */
    GLES20.glBindBuffer(GLES20.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
    checkGlError("glBindBuffer");

    //Draw
    GLES20.glDrawArrays(GLES20.GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 1*9);
    checkGlError("glDrawArrays");

}

/**
 * Utility method for debugging OpenGL calls. Provide the name of the call
 * just after making it:
 *
 * <pre>
 * mColorHandle = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(mProgram, "vColor");
 * MyGLRenderer.checkGlError("glGetUniformLocation");</pre>
 *
 * If the operation is not successful, the check throws an error.
 *
 * @param glOperation - Name of the OpenGL call to check.
 */
public static void checkGlError(String glOperation) {
    int error;
    while ((error = GLES20.glGetError()) != GLES20.GL_NO_ERROR) {
        Log.e("OPEN_GL", glOperation + ": glError " + error);
        throw new RuntimeException(glOperation + ": glError " + error);
    }
}
```

}

#### Solution

Finally I was able to solve the problem (with help of your clues). For all other people who have similar problems, check your shaders and don't just copy & paste them like me. Also [this](http://www.lighthouse3d.com/tutorials/glsl-12-tutorial/data-types-and-variables/) helped me alot. Also here are my now working shaders:

```
final String vertexShader =
        "uniform mat4 uMVPMatrix;      \n"     
                + "attribute vec4 aPosition;     \n"   
                + "attribute vec4 aColor;        \n" 
                + "varying vec4 vColor;          \n"   

                + "void main()                    \n"     
                + "{                              \n"
                + "   vColor = aColor;          \n"
                + "   gl_Position = uMVPMatrix * aPosition;   \n" 
                + "}                              \n";
/* Fragment Shader*/
final String fragmentShader =
        "precision mediump float;" +
        "varying vec4 vColor;" +
        "void main() {" +
        "  gl_FragColor = vColor;" +
        "}";
```

Comment: what does your fragment shader do?

Comment: Have you heara about [libGDX](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/)? It will make your live much easier when learning OpenGl ES. It may not be suitable for your app needs abut it is worth to use it in learning projects.

Comment: Thanks, I'll defenitely look into it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<strike>I'd have to see your Fragment shader to know for certain, but from here, it looks like you're setting the alpha component to 0 in your color array, which means that your colors won't show up. Set the alpha component to 1.</strike>

You need to check and ensure that your fragment shader is compiling correctly. [According to the GLSL_ES specification, shaders need to contain a line at the beginning indicating which version you're using. (Section 3.3, page 9)](https://www.khronos.org/registry/gles/specs/3.0/GLSL_ES_Specification_3.00.4.pdf). Unless you're building for ESGL1.0 (which seems unlikely given your liberal use of Vertex Buffer Objects) that directive has to be present in any valid shader code.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Changing the alpha component to 1 does not change anything. Here is my fragment shader:                             final String fragmentShader =
            "precision mediump float;" +
            "uniform vec4 vColor;" +
            "void main() {" +
            "  gl_FragColor = vColor;" +
            "}";

Comment: you need to upload the vColor uniform, i.e. call glUniform4f() for vColor... I'm not seeing that upload in your original code... If you don't upload a value for the uniform, vColor may be left in a default state (possibly zero'd out which would explain the black triangles, but I think it's driver dependent)... Also, what happens if you assign a contant value to gl_FragColor, e.g. `gl_FragColor = vec4(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);`

Comment: After a short test, I can confirm you are right. Using  GLES20.glUniform4fv(colorHandle,1,colors); works just fine. Thanks for that. But is there a way of buffering the color data in the GPU Memory? Because now I am using a Client Side buffer and have to upload the data every time I want to draw something, or am I wrong?